# ruby: how to access properties specified in config files inside my models and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As title says, I have a yaml file with values like

development:

email:dev@abc.com

test:

email:test@abce.com

production:

prod@abc.com

and i load this file in an rb file located under "initializers" directory as

SpecFile = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/application.yml")

Question is, I need to access these values in my models and controller files.
In html, I refer thme using <%= SpecFile['test']['email']%> which i am not sure is the correct way or not.
(I use ror 1.8.7)

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
spec_file = SpecFile['test']['email']
```

- See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907643/rails-application-settings/2908065#2908065) for full details.